# Why does this trigger an Identifier Expected error in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

The second line in this statement causes an error. I understand if I wrap the lambda in parentheses it solves the problem as in the first line. I'm just curious why it is an error, as in JavaScript a lambda there would work fine.

```
var okay = true && (() => {});
var fails = true && () => {};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a precedence issue:

```
var fails = true && () => {};
                  // <-- Error: Expression expected
```

... is equivalent to:

```
var fails = (true && ()) => {};
```