# Shopify node api context initalize errors out

Tags: node.js, typescript, shopify, shopify-api

I'm trying to make an app following these directions:

https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-node-api/blob/main/docs/getting_started.md

I have all the code configred and it looks like this:

```
// src/index.ts
import http from 'http';
import url from 'url';
import querystring from 'querystring';
import Shopify, { ApiVersion } from '@shopify/shopify-api';
require('dotenv').config();

const { API_KEY, API_SECRET_KEY, SCOPES, SHOP, HOST } = process.env

Shopify.Context.initialize({
  API_KEY,
  API_SECRET_KEY,
  SCOPES: [SCOPES],
  HOST_NAME: HOST.replace(/https?:\/\//, ""),
  HOST_SCHEME: HOST.split("://")[0],
  IS_EMBEDDED_APP: {boolean},
  API_VERSION: ApiVersion.{version} // all supported versions are available, as well as "unstable" and "unversioned"
});

// Storing the currently active shops in memory will force them to re-login when your server restarts. You should
// persist this object in your app.
const ACTIVE_SHOPIFY_SHOPS: { [key: string]: string | undefined } = {};

async function onRequest(
    request: http.IncomingMessage,
    response: http.ServerResponse,
  ): Promise<void> {
    const {headers, url: req_url} = request;
    const pathName: string | null = url.parse(req_url).pathname;
    const queryString: string = String(url.parse(req_url).query);
    const query: Record<string, any> = querystring.parse(queryString);
  
    switch (pathName) {
      default:
        // This shop hasn't been seen yet, go through OAuth to create a session
        if (ACTIVE_SHOPIFY_SHOPS[SHOP] === undefined) {
          // not logged in, redirect to login
          response.writeHead(302, {Location: `/login`});
          response.end();
        } else {
          response.write('Hello world!');
          // Load your app skeleton page with App Bridge, and do something amazing!
        }
        return;
    } // end of default path
  } // end of onRequest()
  
  http.createServer(onRequest).listen(3000);
```

Package JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "shopify-checkout-apit",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@shopify/shopify-api": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^17.0.40",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npx tsc",
    "prestart": "yarn run build",
    "start": "node dist/index.js"
  }
}
```

When I go to run the app with `yarn start` I get a ton of errors

> PS C:\Users\kawnah\shopify-checkout-apit> yarn start yarn run v1.22.18
> $ yarn run build $ npx tsc src/index.ts:17:27 - error TS1003:
> Identifier expected.
>
> 17   API_VERSION: ApiVersion.{version} // all supported versions are
> available, as well as "unstable" and "unversioned"
> ~
>
> src/index.ts:18:1 - error TS1005: ',' expected.
>
> 18 });    ~
>
> Found 2 errors in the same file, starting at: src/index.ts:17
>
> error Command failed with exit code 2. info Visit
> https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this
> command. error Command failed with exit code 2. info Visit
> https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this
> command. PS C:\Users\kawnah\shopify-checkout-apit>

I have no idea what any of this means.

[Typescript Error TS1003 when attempting to access object properties using bracket notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57973690/typescript-error-ts1003-when-attempting-to-access-object-properties-using-bracke)

[Why does this trigger an Identifier Expected error in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830687/why-does-this-trigger-an-identifier-expected-error-in-typescript)

I tried deleting node modules and reinstalling but it didn't work.

How do you fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the config needs to look like this

```
Shopify.Context.initialize({
  API_KEY,
  API_SECRET_KEY,
  SCOPES: [SCOPES],
  HOST_NAME: HOST.replace(/https?:\/\//, ""),
  HOST_SCHEME: HOST.split("://")[0],
  IS_EMBEDDED_APP: true,
  API_VERSION: ApiVersion.October21 // all supported versions are available, as well as "unstable" and "unversioned"
});
```